# How to center one widget among three in a Row?

Tags: flutter

`mainAxisAlignment` to `center` causes all 3 widgets as one to become centered.

How do I center the 2nd widget only, and keep the other two widgets beside the middle 2nd widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create 4 rows , center the middle one with its own alignment. something like this ...

```
Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly
  children: 
  [
    Row(children: [...]), // start or end align here if needed
    Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [...] ),
    Row(children: [...]), // start or end align here if needed
  ],
 ),
```

Comment: Using Text Widgets for the left and right Rows messes up this solution, how do I fix that? [SOLUTION: Add a size to the Text Widgets, make sure both sizes are equal.)

Answer (score 1):

This would center only the second Container and the first and third would be at the start and end position.

```
Row(
      children: 
      [
        Container(),
        Spacer(),
        Container(),
        Spacer(),
        Container(),
      ],
     ),
```